# WiX - add XML element after a specific element

Tags: xml, wix

I need to modify an existing XML file, during installation, so that a new element will be added to the root, but in a specific location (the XML file is order-sensitive).

```
<RootNode>
    <Child1/>
    <Child3/>
</RootNode>
```

should become:

```
<RootNode>
    <Child1/>
    <Child2/>
    <Child3/>
</RootNode>
```

This WiX Component:

```
<Component Id="AddMenuItems" Guid="MyGUID">
    <util:XmlFile Id='XmlAdd' File='[SOMEEXISTINGDIRECTORY]XmlFile.xml' Action='createElement' Name='Child2' ElementPath='//RootNode' Sequence='1'/>
</Component>
```

Generates the following:

```
<RootNode>
    <Child1/>
    <Child3/>
    <Child2/>
</RootNode>
```

Answer (score 1):

if order of child elements is required, then create all the child elements during installation in the required order (add correct sequence) or you have to use custom action dlls to add it at particular order.

Comment: The xml is dynamic, and I can't know all it's elements in advance. I would add all elements during installation if I could iterate them and remove, store, them re-add them with my element in place... anyway, I already wrote a custom  console application to handle this action